# user-dirs.dirs reset at start-up

Tags: gnome3, xdg, xdg-user-dirs

I wanted to have some of the sub-folders of my home directory (like Music, Downloads,Videos) on my hard-disk-raid instead of my SSD. Therefore I deleted those folders in my home directory, recreated them on the RAID and made symlinks pointing from my home-folder to the RAID (e.g. `/home/user/Music > /mnt/home-big-data/user/Music`).

However, the newly created folders don't have the correct meta-data-properties in Gnome 3 (wrong icon, folders won't open as Music folder, etc.).

Which is the best way to remap those features to the folders on the RAID?

I tried editing the `/home/user/.config/user-dirs.dirs` and setting `XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"` (according to the symlink) but it was resetted to `XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/"` after reboot.

Another thing I tried was using `gvfs-set-attribute` to reset the standard-icon, but this also failed.

Which would be the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Most likely, your *user-dirs* are reset to `$HOME/` each time you reboot because those locations are not available on session startup when `xdg-user-dirs-update` is automatically run.

After editing `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` a possible solution is to prevent `xdg-user-dirs-update` from running (and resetting your configuration at each session start up) by adding `enabled=False` to your `user-dirs.conf`:

```
    enabled=boolean
             When set to False, xdg-user-dirs-update will
             not change the XDG user dirs configuration.
```

So to disable it only for your user account, add `enabled=False` to `~/.config/user-dirs.conf` (this will override system-wide settings). If you want to disable it for all users add that key/value to `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.conf`.

Comment: If the `~/.config/user-dirs.conf` does not exists, simply create it with `echo "enabled=False" > ~/.config/user-dirs.conf`

Answer (score 3):

Edit `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`, then run `xdg-user-dirs-update`.

Comment: I tried editing `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` and pointed to the symlinks (like `XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"` not to the "real" path `/mnt/home-big-data/user/Downloads`. I didn't run `xdg-user-dirs-update` but I rebooted the computer - the changes in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` were reverted. Did I make a mistake (except not running `xdg-user-dirs-update`)? (I hope that's not a stupid question, I cannot try it at the moment as I'm not home)

Comment: @Marcel That depends on your particular OS.  The relevant files are `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.conf`, `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults`, and `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`.  Perhaps there are `man` pages or HOWTOs about updating them on your OS.

Comment: it's Debian Stretch x64 with Gnome 3 desktop. Should be exactly as you stated...

Comment: hey @lcd047. I tried your solution (see above in my edited post, thank you), but sadly it didn't work... Do I have any other options to try?

Comment: @Marcel Like I said: your best option is to find docs that describe what you're supposed to do on (the right version of) your OS.  I hopefully pointed you towards _what_ to look for.  I don't have Debian Linux, and I won't venture to guess blindly what contortions the Debian maintainers have come up with, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still has this issue, `xdg-user-dirs-update --force` will solve your woes.

Comment: Using "xdg-user-dirs-update --force"  UNDID the changes I just made in my ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs file.  I would instead like to make my changes to the user-dirs.dirs take effect, in File Manager, Firefox, etc.